# AVI file sizes seem too large

Tags: filesize, avi

Ok, so I'm using the easy cap hooked up to an xbox360 and capturing video files in AMCAP. Now, the video files are output as WMV and a 46 second avi is coming to about 812 MB. But what I'm seeing is that a minute avi should be 19 mb or so. Why are my files so giant???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

them might be uncompressed, try to encode them to h264 or something, eg with help of VLC media player (media -> convert/save)